# not able to return the empty string

Tags: python

"I am not able to return the empty string as per this problem and first part of the problem works great but about the "empty string " issue i am not able return "

```
Given a string s, return a string made of the first 2
# and the last 2 chars of the original string,
# so 'spring' yields 'spng'. However, if the string length
# is less than 2, return instead the empty string.
     def both_ends(s):
# +++your code here+++
         if s <=2:
               return s[:0]
         else :
               return s[0:2] + s[-2:]
```

Comment: Don't you want `if len(s) <= 2:`?

Comment: Should `'ab'` result in  `'ab'` or `'abab'`? Similarly, should `'abc'` result in  `'abc'` or `'abbc'`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `len()` of your input and then `return ''`:

```
def both_ends(s):
    if len(s) < 2:
        return ''
    else:
        return s[:2] + s[-2:]
```

Comment: *However, if the string length is less than 2, return instead the empty string* should be then `< 2` ? But then we would get "1212" for "12" string

Comment: @Reishin Do not use backticks for emphasis. They are meant for code snippets! Use asterisks instead *like this*

Comment: I would upvote if the operator was correctly `<` instead of `<=`. Additionally you could remove the 0 in the first slice.